# Navigator.push() shows a Black Screen

Tags: flutter, screen, navigator

I am trying to make a fruithero flutter app but while changing my main page to another page, It shows only a black screen on my android emulator in laptop and on my phone, but in https://flutlab.io/ it shows perfectly, What is the problem that the app is not working on local emulator or in my phone but working on online IDE

Showing an Eror like this: -

> There are multiple heroes that share the same tag within a subtree.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './detailsPage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF21BFBD),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0, left: 10.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => DetailsPage(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 125.0,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.filter_list),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 25.0,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Healthy',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Mont',
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 25.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                Text(
                  'Food',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Mont', color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 40.0,
          ),
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 185.0,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(75.0))),
            child: ListView(
              primary: false,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 20.0),
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45.0),
                  child: Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.68,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildFoodItem('images/one.png', 'Salmon', '\$24.0'),
                        _buildFoodItem('images/two.png', 'Spring', '\$22.0'),
                        _buildFoodItem('images/three.png', 'Sprite', '\$34.0'),
                        _buildFoodItem('images/one.png', 'Mut', '\$12.0')
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: 65.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 65.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 6,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.shopping_cart,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 65.0,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xff170F1F),
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid,
                            width: 1.0,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        'Checkout',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontFamily: 'Mont',
                        ),
                      )),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildFoodItem(String imgPath, String foodName, String price) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(                                               //Here is the Navigator.push()
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return DetailsPage();
            }),
          );
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Hero(
                    tag: imgPath,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(imgPath),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      height: 75.0,
                      width: 75.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        foodName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Mont',
                            fontSize: 17.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        price,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Mont',
                            fontSize: 15.0,
                            color: Colors.grey),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Navigator.push code is like this:

> Navigator.push(
>               context,
>               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
>                 return DetailsPage();
>               }),
>             );

detailsPage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsPageState createState() => _DetailsPageState();
}

class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF7A9BEE),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          'Details',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'Mont',
            fontSize: 18.0,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is git Repository link: [1](https://github.com/jobinjose0010/fruithero.git)

Answer (score 0):

i dont see the hero widget in the detailsPage.dart, when you set up a Hero widget in main and Navigate to detailsPage, you have to set up a hero widget to receive a hero transition from the main page, and because you have a listView in main you have to give a dynamic tag to each list item because each hero must have a tag associated with it so when it transfer to different layout it knows which hero to transit to it,
you already set up a hero tag in main page and you already give it a tag as  tag: imgPath
tag is like an id for that hero, now you need to set the same tag (id) in the detailsPage,
please watch this to understand the logic [Hero Flutter Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Be9UH1kXFDw)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Hero Widgets on both screens.

I couldn't find the **Hero widget**, nor the **tag** and not the **image** that you used on your first screen too (`AssetImage(imgPath)`)

Try and parameterize using the propoer Hero specs.

Here you can find an good example and instructions: [Flutter example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/hero-animations)